# String.split on dot doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have a string = 12.05.2014

And I am trying to use split by "." but it is returning empty array for some reason.

```
System.out.println(newDate);
System.out.println(newDate.length());
String [] dateCells = newDate.split(".");

StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sBuilder.append(dateCells[2]).append(dateCells[0]).append(dateCells[1]);
System.out.println(sBuilder.toString());
```

The output is:

```
12.05.2014
10
            //empty line
```

Comment: The split method takes a _regular expression_ so you need to escape the dot i.e. `split("\\.")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` uses regex and in regex `.` means "any character beside line separators".

So you split on each character creating array full of empty elements like

```
"foo".split(".")
```

would at first create `["","","",""]`, but since `split` also trails empty elements placed at the end of array you would get empty array `[]`. Trailing last empty strings can be turned off with overloaded version of split `split(regex,limit)` by passing negative value as `limit`.

To solve this problem you need to escape `.`. To do this you can use for instance

- `split("\\.")` - standard escape in regex
- `split("[.]")` - escaping using [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `split("\\Q.\\E")` - `\Q` and `\E` mark area in which regex metacharacters should be treated as simple literals
- `split(Pattern.quote("."))` - this method uses `Pattern.LITERAL` flag inside regex compiler to point that metacharacters used in regex are simple literals without any special meaning

Another problem would be condition in your `for` loop but more about it in [Jeroens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23666730/1393766).

Answer (score 4):

Your condition is

```
for(int i = dateCells.length; i < 0; i--){
```

It starts at `3` and runs *while* your counter is less than `0`. Which it never is.

Obvious solution: either use `i > 0` or change it up to loop from `0` to `3`.

Additionally: don't forget to escape the dot which is a special regex character. Escaping is done through a backslash (`\`) but since that backslash is also a special character, you have to escape it as well.

End result:

```
.split("\\.")
```

Comment: will fix that , but when i deubg , the datecell array is empty

Comment: @fadytaher And *that* is because the argument to `split` is a regular expression. Escape the `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you need to escape `.` when splitting on it, because `String.split()` treats `.` as a regex.

```
public class Foo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hi = "hello.world.good.bye";
        String[] parts = hi.split("\\.");
        for (int i = 0;i < parts.length; i++)
            System.out.println(parts[i]);
    }
}
```